# Download the deployment package of Lambda function using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am building a solution to manage the migration of AWS Lambdas from one region/account to another. AWS's Lambda dashboard currently only supports exporting Lambdas one at a time, which will be too slow for me.

I want to use boto3's `client.get_function(...)` and `client.create_function(...)` to automate this.

[Following the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.get_function), I use `client.get_function("myFunc")` to get my function's config and code details:

```
response = client.get_function(FunctionName = "myFunc")
fConfig = response["Configuration"]
fCode = response["Code"]
print(fCode)

>>> 'RepositoryType': 'S3',
    'Location': 'https://awslambda-us-east-2-tasks.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/snapshots/1234567890123/myFunc-d6abcd8d-8a83...'
```

My question is how do I use `fCode["Location"]` to download the Lambda's deployment package so that I can later use it when I call `client.create_function(...)`?

I have read the boto3 S3 docs, but couldn't find anything that would help me there. Simply following the 'Location' link returns: `AccessDenied: No AWSAccessKey was presented.`

If someone could please explain how `response["Code"]` is meant to be used.

Comment: isnt that a lot easier if you create a clouformation template or serverless template and use to it deploy in different region ?

Answer (score 3):

Below is a snippet of code that downloads the Lambda to the tmp dir on the local machine.

```
import requests
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

# Download the lambda
def download_lambda(function_arn):

   tmp_dir = '/tmp/' 
         
   arn = function_arn
   arn_parts = arn.split(':')
   func_name = arn_parts[6]
   
   func_details = lambda_client.get_function(FunctionName=function_arn)
   zip_file = tmp_dir + func_name + '.zip'
   url = func_details['Code']['Location']
   
   r = requests.get(url)
   with open(zip_file, "wb") as code:
      code.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Korgen pointed out, the `get_function` command returns a [S3 presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

I have successfully generated and used a download URL using `boto3` in a lambda with the default Basic Execution Role plus the `get_function` permission.  No further permissions (e.g. no S3 permissions) are required.

The URL can be used by anyone (e.g. you can paste it into the browser). The URL does, however, **expire after 10 minutes** (`X-Amz-Expires=599` header).  This is a feature of the presigned URL, that it is public, but short-lived.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the `Location` returned by `get_function` returns a presigned S3 URL. That means you should be able to just download the zip package by `GET`ing this URL.
You can then use the zip as input to `create_function`.

I haven't tried with boto but when I use the AWS cli's  `aws lambda get-function --function-name <A_FUNCTION_NAME>` it works like described. I can open the URL in a browser and am able to download the zip of the function.

For me it seems that the credentials/role used by boto is not allowed to call s3:GetObject on the resource.

Can you try if it works with the aws cli (make sure to use the same role/user as from within boto)!?

Comment: Thanks Korgen. Calling this from the CLI using my main AWS credentials allows me to download the file without hitting `AccessDenied: No AWSAccessKey was presented`. So I suspect that the IAM credentials I'm using in my function do not have the required user permissions. So my next question, what permissions do I need to attach to this user?

Comment: I assume s3:GetObject permissions for the S3 Object and maybe s3:ListBucket on the bucket... haven't tried it though.
The doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html says "Anyone with valid security credentials can create a presigned URL. However, in order to successfully access an object, the presigned URL must be created by someone who has permission to perform the operation that the presigned URL is based upon."